# How to download .deb package?? in usb

Tags: command-line

How can I download a `.deb` file in USB device and from that USB device install that package to other devices??

Comment: Which package do you want to download?, Download it, copy it to your USB device and just double click it in the computer where you want to install it.

Answer (score 0):

On another computer, open the terminal, and go the flash drive with the `cd /media/your_username/drive_name` command on Ubuntu. Next, run:

```
apt download package_name
```

and the `.deb` file will be downloaded onto the flash drive. Next, go onto the computer you would like to install the package on, and in a terminal, run:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file.deb
```

Be sure that both machines have the same CPU architecture, or else there will be errors. If this is the case, just search for the deb file online for the right CPU architecture(i.e. `x86_64`)

Also, as noted by wjandrea, both computers should be the same version of Ubuntu, or you may run into problems.

Comment: Don't the two machines also need to be the same version of Ubuntu? E.g. the `python3` package for 14.04 has Python 3.4, but for 17.10 it has Python 3.6.

Comment: I don't know. I think older packages might work on newer systems, but not the other way around.